# How to add a new map field inside a parent map field in Firestore?

Tags: database, vue.js, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, field

I want to add a new map field inside another map field.
My data structure looks like this:
[image]

I want to add a 'field b' after 'field a' inside 'Filed 1' (pardon my typo).

my code looks like this

```
 const collsRef = doc(db, "collections", collectionUid); // get the right document
 await setDoc(collsRef, { sellectData }, { merge: true });
```

but not only this is giving me an error, I believe this code would only add a new field at the same level as 'Filed 1'

[image]

the data type triggering the unsupported field value error is an JS object like so – do I need to parse it before comiting it to the db?

[image]

I've blanked out data and left the structure and syntax because it contained personal sensitive  data. I hope it's enough to explain the problem.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `sellectData` structure looks like but you have to construct an object that has the same structure from Firestore. See sample code below:

```
const collsRef = doc(db, "collections", collectionUid);

let sellectData = {
  "field b": { "key b" : "value b" }
}

await setDoc(collsRef, { 
  "Filed 1": sellectData
}, { merge: true });
```

This would result in (already corrected your typo):
[image]

---

Update:

You have two options to set the object key as a variable.

You need to make the object first, then use `[]` to set it.:

```
let key = "Field 1";
let sellectData = {
  "field b": { "key b" : "value b" }
}

await setDoc(collsRef, {
  [key]: sellectData
}, { merge: true });
```

Or, by contructing the object itself.

```
let key = "Field 1";

let sellectData = {
  [key] : { "field b": 
    { "key b" : "value b" }
  }
}

// Remove the curly brackets `{}` in this case.
await setDoc(collsRef, 
  sellectData, 
  { merge: true });
```

---

For more information, see [Update fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Comment: Thank you Marc! that worked but I had to use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(OBJ)) to get rid of the invalid data error. Unfortunately I need 'Filed 1' value to be a variable (it will change from case to case) and with this solution (even if I attribute it a value and remove the quotes) it's interpreted and written as a string. Is it even possible to force Firestore to take it as a variable inside a setDoc function?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. I've updated my answer.